# ¿JWT por la cookie para web?

Tags: laravel, jwt

Buenas chicos.

Estoy creando una aplicación, donde el login es realizado en un servicio tanto para api como para la web.

Para la api no hay problema porque se manda en la cabecera, pero no entiendo cómo lo uso en la web. Si hago una petición por ajax le incluyo la cabecera, pero ¿qué pasa cuando la petición es por el metodo get...? no sé cómo incluir el token en la petición, no sé si usar cookie es la forma correcta... quisiera saber si pueden darme un ejemplo de como tratarlo desde la web.

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

Existe ya una [librería](http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation/) que te lo hace todo automático ya

Comment: en la documentacion de la api no espeficica para la web como es la forma correcta de enviarla.. solo dice q por ajax y alternativamente por la url

Comment: En cuanto implementes el middleware se mandara solo en el header de la peticion